# WPF DataGrid is not rendered properly after Changing underlying collection

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, c#-4.0

Here's my code:

```
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Button" Click="button1_Click" />
    <DataGrid ItemsSource ="{Binding Lst}"  />
</Grid>
```

Code-Behind:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (this.DataContext as Some).remove();
    }
```

DataSource is:

```
  public class Some : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<Point> lst = new List<Point>();
    public List<Point> Lst
    {
        get
        {
            return lst;
        }
    }

    public Some()
    {
        lst.Add(new Point(2.3, 5));
        lst.Add(new Point(267.3, 5));
        lst.Add(new Point(2.3, 65));
        lst.Add(new Point(2.63, 885));
        lst.Add(new Point(27.3, 65));

    }
    public void remove()
    {
        lst.Remove(lst.Last());
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Lst"));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

When i call `remove()` method, i delete item from the collection and invoke propertychanged. UI reaction is: i cannot properly select cells in datagrid which correspond to deleted `Point`. They are **not** removed. This looks like UI bug, is there any workaround?

Sorry for it's so dirty - just a quick sample.

Thanks, Ilya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ObservableCollection<>` instead of `List<>` for Lst - the ObservableCollection automatically notifies when the collection changes through adds, removes or clears. You will also need a DependencyProperty: http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/12664.aspx

Comment: Thanks! Now i know what ObservableCollection is used for :)

Comment: The dependency property is not necessary. You can use view model simply by implementing INotifyPropertyChanged and INotifyCollectionChanged interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

I case of binding `ItemSource` to a view model, your collection should implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`. The `ObsevableCollection` in fact is the collection that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`, thus notifying WPF controls of the added and removed elements.